# Apps and App Parts

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I'm looking at creating a SharePoint 2013 provider hosted app, and wondering about whether to expose it as a straight app (and use the client chrome control for branding) or as an app part to be added to a page. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0942fdce-3227-496a-8873-399fc1dbb72c),

> UI: There are three ways to surface an app for SharePoint in SharePoint: at a minimum, all apps are surfaced in a full web page. Optionally, an app can also be surfaced through an app part, and through a menu item or ribbon button.

Are there any benefits or side effects to surfacing the app as an app part that can be added to web part pages, as well as the full web part page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surfacing an app as app part is like using a web part on a page in traditional development. The navigation (left navigation, top navigation, etc) is retained. However, if you simply use an app, then by default you get a chrome control which helps in navigating back to SharePoint host web and also applies the styles. However, you loose all navigation (like top navigation, left navigation). So, if you don't want your users not to make use of Hostweb navigation and want to create your own navigation then you can create an app without surfacing it from app part.

Comment: So if I surface the app as an app part, can the user open the app directly as well?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend create an sharepoint hosted app and upload to 365 to start with
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379

OR design patterns for app
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/04/09/apps-for-sharepoint-page-patterns.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/jj220046.aspx

Comment: I'm able to create the app (provider-hosted in our case), I'm just wondering what I gain or lose by creating an app part for users to add to a page.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95023/sharepoint-app-vs-object-model

Comment: It is not a question about what app model to use, but rather to crate or not create a client webpart with it

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below articles on differences between provider hosted and SharePoint hosted app.
Based on your requirement you can choose whoch one is best.
http://www.jeremythake.com/2014/02/sharepoint-apps-playbook-series-part-2-sharepoint-hosted-vs-provider-hosted-2/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179887.aspx

As Nikhil suggested you can start with SharePont hosted app, If that is not meeting your requirements you can use provider hosted app.

http://officeams.codeplex.com/ codeplex solution covered lot of examples which you can leverage while building the apps.

Comment: It is not a question about what app model to use, but rather to crate or not create a client webpart with it